# Openshift haproxy logformat for ssl logging

Tags: openshift, haproxy-ingress

Need help with logformat string to be set for haproxy 2.2.48 version used by Openshift 4.10 for logging ssl related attributes for trouble shooting ssl connection failures like sal cert, chiper, ssl error etc. right now it just prints

fe/sni: SSL client certificate not trusted.

Tried enabling the httpslogformat in the ingresscontroller resource, it safely ignores, if i use the httplogformat and apply ssl related  aatributes haproxy fails to start

Comment: Have you tried setting `ingresscontroller.spec.logging.access.httpLogFormat` ?

Comment: Yes, but if I add any ssl related logs haproxy fails to start with error saying it can’t find those. There is a separate httpslogformat in haproxy. Wondering how could i specify that for openshift haproxy?

Comment: Please add more details what you've done. For instance, add Yaml files you modified or add command lines you executed.
Only thing I can find difference is you wrote the keyword `httpslogformat` but I wrote it without `s` like `httplogformat`.